# In my external css tag is working but another defined class is not working

Tags: html, css

In my external css tag is working but another defined class is not working.
**I have defined two classes in my external CSS file, 1st one of them is working but 2nd one class is not working with external CSS. both classes work properly if I write these codes on my HTML page.**

//code of external css page;

```
.container{
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  align-items: center;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.userCircle{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:10px;
  border: #fff 2px solide; 
}


//code of the HTML page

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Profile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.3/css/intlTelInput.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.3/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>

  
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>




<!----------------Custome Links---------------->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/profile.css">
<!----------------/Custome Links---------------->


</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col">

         <h3>User Details</h3>

           <div class="userCircle">
           User Id : <?php echo $uid; ?>
           </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain which one is working and which one is not

Comment: You have a spelling error, solid not solide. I guess you don’t have that in your HTML-included version.

Comment: The container is working and but userCircle is not working

Comment: Thanks for the spelling suggestion but my issue is something else